# Android Application is not being launched, Screen Lock

Tags: java, android, screen-lock

I am creating a screen lock for android phones. If my device is connected to PC via usb, it is launching correctly. But if I unplug the usb cable and start application again, it says application unfortunately closed. Any help regarding this issue... Thanks

Comment: Please post your stack trace from LogCat.

Comment: It is working in usb debugging mode only. After unpluging usb cable, when I launch the app from phone, it throws exception that Unfortunately Door lock has stoped....

Comment: Just leave your phone connected but launch it from the phone.

Comment: I tried it. It is launching correctly. But when I unplug the phone and try to run it from phone, it shows exception.